# Unable to save .xlsx file as .csv with special characters

Tags: excel, csv, utf-8, vbscript

I am trying to take a .xlsx file, which contains several special characters from addresses such as ß, delivered as an email attachment, save it and then convert it to a csv file which still includes all the characters.  The process works but the csv file has modified the special characters.  I believe this relates to the encoding of the file.  The current process uses VBA to save the file, then calls a .vbs to convert it.

I tried to force the final csv file to be saved in xlsUTF8 format by setting csv_format =62 but it fails with that as an an unexpected argument.

The next thing I have tried is saving the file as a txt file then converting to csv but this does not seem to have resolved the issue.

The process runs on a machine with Excel 2016 installed.  I am not experienced with scripting so the code below has been borrowed from colleagues, and I am sure it could be tidied up considerably.  Apologies in advance for any schoolboy errors.

VBA

```
Public Sub FileSave(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    'Declare variables
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim archiveFolder As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim dateFormat As String

    dateFormat = Format(Now, "ddmmyyyy_hhnnss")
    saveFolder = "C:\File\"
    archiveFolder = "C:\File\Archive\"
    Filename = "Test.xlsx"

         For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
                Dim fso
                Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                'Check to see if file exists in saveFolder directory.
                'If it already exists then move to achiveFolder location and rename with time/date stamp.
                If fso.FileExists(saveFolder & Filename) Then
                    fso.CopyFile saveFolder & Filename, archiveFolder & Filename
                    fso.MoveFile archiveFolder & Filename, archiveFolder & dateFormat & "_OLD.xlsx"
                    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & Filename
                    Set objAtt = Nothing
                'If it does not exist then copy attachment to saveFolder directory.
                Else
                    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & Filename
                    Set objAtt = Nothing
                End If

         Next
    Shell "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe C:\File\Remove_trailing_lines.vbs", 1
End Sub
```

VBS 'Remove_Trailing_Lines.vbs'

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateUnicode = -1, TristateASCII = 0
Set objFSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\File\Test.xlsx", ForReading, false, TristateUseDefault)
strContents = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

'Remove trailing lines from file
intLength = Len(strContents)
for i=intLength to 1 step -1
    if Mid(strContents,i,1)=Chr(10) or Mid(strContents,i,1)=Chr(13) then    
        strContents = Mid(strContents,1,Len(strContents)-1)
    else
        exit for
    end if
next

txt_format =42
csv_format =6
Dim objExcel
Dim objBook
Dim objBook_xls
Dim objSheet
Dim objWshShell

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objBook = objExcel.WorkBooks.Open("C:\File\Test.xlsx", ForWriting, True)
Set objSheet = objBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set objWshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

'Tidy up rows and column names
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objBook.SaveAs "C:\File\Test.txt", txt_format
objBook.Close False

Set objBook_txt = objExcel.WorkBooks.Open("C:\File\Test.txt", ForWriting, True)

'Save to csv from txt
objBook_txt.SaveAs "C:\File\Test.csv", csv_format
objBook_txt.Close False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = true
objExcel.Quit

WScript.Quit
```

If anyone can help me with the process I would be very grateful.

Dave

Comment: What does *"the csv file has modified the special characters"* exactly mean? What was changed and to what was it changed? • Did you try  `xlCSVWindows = 23` as CSV format? And without saving it as text before as this should work without that.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the format to xlCSVWindows = 23 and will run it again soon.  Will this be saved as ANSI encoding?  The problem I had was originally my source file seemed to be sending through a character xA0 (when viewed as UTF8, I believe it is a NO-BREAK SPACE but I cannot see it in the source file) and this was causing the downstream process to break.   Again aplogies if this is not clear, this is not really my usual job.

Comment: An example of the issue
In the source Excel file I see this Donaustraße 16,
In the csv file (ANSI csv = 23) I see this Donaustraße 16, 
In the downstream application it is displaying as Donaustraߥ 16

Another example is the Düsseldorf appears as D쳳eldorf

I was hoping that if I sent the csv as UTF8 it would work?

Comment: Ah so if your CSV is showing correctly then the downstream application is not reading it properly. So I guess the downstream application is the issue here. Check the coding of the CSV eg using Notepad++. There you can (as a first test) also convert the coding to UTF8 in Notepad++ and check if it is then readable in your downstream process. So you can narrow down to what is working.

Comment: Thanks again.  My file is modified by a third party app, and it appears that is causing the problem downstream.  There was a character that was being read as a break.  The application owner is updating their code to resolve it.  Thanks again for the tip about saving the file straight to csv.

Comment: I know most people stick on their technology stack for reasons, but did you consider using PowerShell's built in `Export-CSV` and `Import-xlsx` from PSExcel? It looks like your approach could be done in 3 to 4 PowerShell lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at PS, it is not something I have used very much.